# an issue with cvGetCaptureProperty on opencv

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, ubuntu-11.10

I have a working opencv code that takes feed from my webcam and displays it. (The code is modified from the one [here](http://www.iis.uni-stuttgart.de/lehre/ss08/ComputerVision/hellovideo.cpp)

The only issue is that when I try to print the frames-per-second value, as

```
int fps = (int) cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
printf ("Frames per Second: %d\n",fps);
```

-1 gets printed.

Another (side) issue is that there appears to be some run time errors/warnings

```
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
select timeout
HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L2: Unable to get property <unknown property string>(5) - Invalid argument
HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L: Property <unknown property string>(2) not supported by device
HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L2: Unable to get property <unknown property string>(1) - Invalid argument
HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L: Property <unknown property string>(2) not supported by device
```

But the code does what it's supposed to do, ie, display video from the webcam.

Any ideas how to sort out the problems? I am using opencv on Eclipse with CDT on Ubuntu 11.10

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the error messages, this sounds like a problem your webcam driver. The error messages are from Video4Linux (V4L or V4L2 in the error messages), which is the part of the Linux kernel that contains webcam drivers. Getting a `select()` failure and the "not supported by device" error message probably means that your webcam didn't implement this part of the V4L2 API.

You can verify that this is the problem by testing your code with a camera that has a known-good driver. Unfortunately, this is very common in the webcam drivers included in the kernel. Many of them are reverse engineered, so it's quite a feat just access the video stream.

Comment: thanks, but then what about the -1 value of fps? any idea about that?

Comment: The error messages you listed are not a "side issue;" they're actually the root of the problem. OpenCV cannot query the driver for the FPS (which causes the error messages), so it returns an error code (-1). I am not sure why the OpenCV docs say the error code should be 0; it's possible that this is a bug or the docs are out-of-date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the HIGHGUI ERROR errors:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so
```

Comment: you should explain what that does